# Pagination issue in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Well, I have a problem with sorting and pagination in the data array in Vue.js
Sorting works fine, but pagination is not working properly so, because for example when I skip to 10th page and then use filters, they stay in the empty field and do not display the results. Then I can skip to the first page and Now I can see results.

HTML:

```
    <tr v-for="(family,index) in fileteredArray">
    <p style="float:right;margin-right:5px;"><i v-if="current!=1 && current>0" @click="prev()" style="color:#0575ff;margin-right:15px;" class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i> <i v-else style="color:#54595f;margin-right:15px;" class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i> <span v-for="number in count" ><b style="padding:2px" v-if="number==current">{{number}}</b><small v-else>{{number}}</small></span><i v-if="current<pagesAmount()" @click="next()" style="color:#0575ff;margin-left:15px" class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i><i v-else style="color:#54595f;margin-left:15px" class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></p>

    data(){
    return {
    current: 1,
    pageSize:5,
    pageAmount:false,
    currentArray:[],
    families: []
}}


   



       
computed: {
     fileteredArray: function(){
                 
    return this.paginated(this.filterProductsBySomething1(filterProductsBySomething2(this.this.families)));
            },
   indexStart() {
          return (this.current - 1) * this.pageSize;
        },
   indexEnd() {
          return this.indexStart + this.pageSize;
        },
   count: function(){
          return Math.round(this.currentArray.length / this.pageSize);
        }
      },
    }

    methods:{
    prev() {
          
          this.current--;
        },
        next() {
          this.current++;
    },
    filterProductsBySomething1: function(array){
           return array.filter(family => array.field.includes("xxx"));
        },
        filterProductsBySomething2: function(array){
          return array.filter(family => array.field.includes("xxx")) ;
        },
    
     paginated(array) {
      this.currentArray=array;
      return array.slice(this.indexStart, this.indexEnd);
    },
```

Comment: Hi, please format your code to have something more readable here please.

Comment: When you filter, change page to number 1? So this.current = 1

Comment: where should i add it ?

Comment: In your 'fileteredArray' function, above the return

Comment: When I do this I can't change page in pagination.